# “Storyrize” a fact

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose Person A wants to tell a factual event/happening to Person B, and Person A does not want to mention names, or whatever certain details. (Perhaps he is talking about himself but he is too shy to admit that.) He tells it in such a way that as if it is a story. But Person B knows that it is a fact, even if told in the manner it is narrated. (Or it may be that Person A wants to complain about something but he does not to appear as someone who complains.)

What verb would describe Person A's action? I first thought of “storytelling,” but I don't think it conveys the idea that what is told is not a story.

Comment: @HotLicks, michael.hor257k Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
question,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions.

Comment: Thank you for asking. Some information before we start will help us to give you the correct answer.
Please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.
Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Answer (score 3):

**Fictionalize** would indeed work here.

Depending on the nature of the fictionalization, **parable** can be used.

> Person A parables the event to Person B.

[source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parable)

That may imply too much fiction, though.

You might then consider bending **hypothesize** to your meaning. I don't believe this is standard usage in any standard, but it should get the idea across. (Or torture hypothetical into service.)

> Person A hypotheticals the event to Person B.